# PHP Dynamic Gallery Pagination (with a twist)

Tags: javascript, pagination

well i am displaying a dynamic gallery using PHP... what i want is to instead of showing a lot of thumbnails on one page i rather do paging.. you know the number pages and next and all..

well its an old thing but i don't know how to do this..

- HOW TO DO IT ?

but hold your horses **HERES THE TWIST**

i am showing thumbnails in DIVS which i set in line so lets say if someone open the page in 1024x768 i get 3 thumbnails in a row and and there are 6 rows so they make 18 thumnails on the whole..

but if someone open the page with their resolution lets say 1600 x 1200 i get 5 thumnails in a row so 18 thumbnails would make 3 rows.. lets say i want to keep the rows 6 and pop up the thumbnails to 30... **HOW TO RIDE A CODE TO DO THAT**

p.s. best of luck with my crazy thangs....

Comment: This sounds like an HTML/CSS question, not a PHP question...

Comment: well i didn't knew Pagination was possible with HTML\CSS... o wait did HTML & CSS just went dynamic... read through the question first bro

Comment: I did read the question.  It is possible to have images automatically flow within a DIV; I forget how (it's been a while since I've used CSS).  If you want to do something more complicated than simply have your images flow gracefully, then you need to make your question a *lot* clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic technique is this:  You know, or else calculate, how many images you're displaying per page.  So when you do your query, that's your LIMIT.  Also, you're going to need an offset - how many results you need to skip over.  If you were showing 8 results per page and you wanted to show the 3rd page, your offset would be (3 - 1) * 8, or 16.

Now, your interesting challenge sounds like your display:  You're showing different amounts of thumbnails based on the display.  So you will need to calculate how big of a display you want, probably with javascript, and then make an ajax request to query for the amount of results you want and the offset, based on the page you're showing.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination can be handled in PHP. But you can't do all of what you mentioned in pure PHP. Some AJAX/Javascript will be involved, specifically in auto-detection of browser resolution. You do have to consider clients with browsers that have portrait and landscape dimensions, including small screens (mobile phones 240x240 or 320x320).

Answer (score 1):

Granted that *somehow* you manage to get a hold on the user's resolution and that you will be able to compute the total number of thumbnails in a DIV, then it's no magic to tell PHP to go with 30 thumbnails instead.

```
define('ROW_TOTAL',   6);
define('MIN_THUMBS',  3);
define('THUMB_WIDTH', 320);

// Get the clients resolution (i.e. via ECMA and a cookie)
$thumbs = isset($_COOKIE['res_width']) ?
    (int) (intval($_COOKIE['res_width'], 10) / THUMB_WIDTH) : MIN_THUMBS;

// Get the page via the client's request
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ?
    intval($_GET['page'], 10) : 0;

$query = sprintf(
    'SELECT thumb_url' .
     ' FROM images' .
    ' WHERE set_id = %u'.
    ' LIMIT %u OFFSET %u',
    $set_id,
    $thumbs,
    $thumbs * $page
);

// Feth the records and process them in a loop
// I'll leave that up to you
```

Good luck,
aefxx

Answer (score 0):

you can find screen resolution by java script

**document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);**

this line will print the screen resolution. so can go for further step as-usual by if condition

> if($screen = 1024x768) { execute query
>   } else { execute query }

I hope This will help you..