# Any PHP Library/Class for Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP pagination class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465999/php-pagination-class)

are there any PHP/Class libraries that i can utilize & customize with my solutions... i am just looking for that to avoid the trouble of coding a lot and all....

Comment: probably it would be great to know for which framework if you are using one.

Comment: pagination for dynamic web gallery...

Comment: if it's for a web gallery, then how is the question different from [your previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173975/php-dynamic-gallery-pagination-with-a-twist)?

Comment: I don't get it. What's the *coding a lot* issue with pagination exactly? Isn't it just that thing where you output a number list if more results are to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

- [Finally, the simple pagination class](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/)

[See the demo here](http://www.catchmyfame.com/paginator/example.php)

Comment: @Junaid Saeed: There is explanation of how to implement that also. As for code sample it is also there or you can download it here: http://www.catchmyfame.com/paginator/catchmyfame-pagination-example-files.zip

Answer (score 0):

Could try [Pear Data Pager](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager) or [Zend_Paginator](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.html).